# Which [security]? [cybersecurity]! Aren't those supposed to be synonyms in our context?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, clean-up

I stumbled on the tags [cybersecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cybersecurity) and [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security) and tried to imagine if there is a difference between questions that would go in either tag. In the context of Stack Overflow that is.

I couldn't come up with a valid case and a short poll in SOCVR (n = 2) didn't return a different viewpoint.

Am I correct that these tags might be a synonym of each other? If yes, can a mod create a synonym so that [cybersecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cybersecurity) goes into [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security).

Looking over some questions in [cybersecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cybersecurity) I get the feeling a clean-up is in order as well. If you have votes and a few minutes to spare please evaluate the Q/A's in that tag and vote/flag accordingly.

Comment: I have gone through most questions and voted to close a whole lot of them. Some belong to [InfoSec.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), others are too broad and/or not about programming at all. [Close queue link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=cybersecurity)

Comment: Yeah... what would be on-topic for SO regarding this? Cybersecurity questions belong to [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), Generic doubts regarding building secure systems are better suited in [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and worries about the security of a specific implementation would go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I would only see this tag on-topic in SO for doubts regarding implementation of a specific cybersecurity tool/pattern, and just as a secondary tag.

Comment: @MarcSances I could maybe see a question about implementing some security-related functionality in a specific code example in a specific language. Programmers could be experts in implementing security features in a particular language. Such questions would only be appropriate for Code Review if they're already working. Any such questions about code that *isn't* working properly would belong here.

Comment: @TylerH too many conditionals and hand waving on those statements. If trying to come up with good ways is basically unattainable, best not having them.

Comment: @Braiam it's not really any different than the requirements we already put forward for any other kind questions. *All* questions need to be specific and about a particular language, unless they're *specifically* about pseudo-code/language-agnostic implementations. To be clear, the 3rd and 4th sentences of my comment above are a separate comment that cover counter-arguments to Marc's suggestion that "specific implementation Qs go to Code Review"

Comment: @TylerH I've already stated that "doubts regarding implementation of a specific cybersecurity tool/pattern" would be on-topic for SO. I've stated Code Review case _only_ for working code where there are doubts regarding its security. Either way, even in such on-topic cases, the cybersecurity tag would be secondary, since the main tag would be, for example, [tag:ssl]. You implement _something_ (library/tool/pattern/algorithm) related to cybersecurity, you don't implement "cybersecurity" on its own.

Comment: Just because a question is *on-topic* for Information Security Stack Exchange, doesn't necessarily make it *off-topic* for Stack Overflow. If it's the type of question that a programmer who isn't a specialist in security can answer, it can stay in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I really don't know what "cybersecurity" is... is it an actual thing, or just a buzz word that people who don't have a clue about technology in general use? Like "IT", "IoT" and other such nonsense terms? It would at least seem that most people using the tag have no clue what it means either.

Comment: @Lundin In the US at least, "cyber" as a prefix implies the Internet as a whole. I mean, the past few Presidents have had a post [they call cyber czar](https://thehill.com/policy/cybersecurity/544124-biden-under-growing-pressure-to-nominate-cyber-czar), which refers to Internet security.

Comment: @Machavity I believe the term "cyberspace" pre-dates the Internet by many decades.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, but that term has been used as a synonym for the Internet for decades. [It's more or less official now](https://www.cybercom.mil/)

Comment: @Machavity At any rate it feels like a superfluous tag that should simply be removed and replaced with [security], rather than made a synonym.

Comment: @Lundin I could live with that. Only reason for synomizing is to prevent it gets recreated. I mean: someone managed to get that tag invented in the past. Some restless soul surely recreates it in 6 to 8 weeks again ...

Comment: Yes, SO is broken because anyone and their mother can create any tag at a whim. Too late to fix it now.

Comment: @MarcSances You *didn't* mention "working code" for Code Review, hence that part of my comment in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

It looked like it was mostly cleaned (lots of closure). Deleted a few that wouldn't Roomba. Synonym is now added. Can merge later.